# How do I get a compilable result from objdump?

Tags: c, linux, objdump

```
objdump -S --disassemble Test> Test.s
```

Then

```
gcc Test.s
```

Apparently, it does not work.

Is there any option I can specify to `objdump` to get compilable assembly?

Comment: Short answer - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do, is called "decompile". There are some languages which can be decompiled, Java being the best known of them, but C (or C++) are not decompilable.